questdb can't flush table
I have python code that gets data and tries to insert it into a questdb table:
conf = f'http::addr=localhost:9000;'
                with Sender.from_conf(conf) as sender:
                    sender.dataframe(data, table_name=ticker, at='Date')

I have been able to insert thousands of table this way. However, if I've dropped the table before, I get error:
Could not flush buffer: failed to parse line protocol:errors encountered on line(s):write error: AAPL, errno: -102, error: table is dropped [dirName=AAPL~14566, tableName=AAPL] [id: 7d5deaaffd54-9941, code: internal error, line: 1]

If I go to the GUI console and try to remove this 'AAPL' table, it says it doesn't exist! I am at a loss as to what to try next.
How do I clear the metadata that is preventing me from adding this table?

It looks like a bug, I'd recommend creating an issue in GitHub https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues for it
